# Image Not Showing In RecyclerView

Tags: firebase, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am working on Android Application that Contains room database to store `**imagespath**` and Content for that image. I am retrieving that Image Path and getting image from that path and showing that image in **`recyclerview`**. The Issue I am facing is, if the Image size is greater then It don't show Image If Image Size is Grater or Contain More Data in QR Bitmap.

I am Unable to Understand what the Issue Actually Is...

Like I have Added this Image

[image]

If the Image Size is Larger then the image Dont showed and I see blank in Imageview.

My layout of Custom Adapter Looks like

```
 <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/constmainscan"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/edittextbackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.64"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgrecyclerviewscan"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_90sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_90sdp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txt_detailscan"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_detailscan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_light"
        android:text="@string/email"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolorblack"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_14sdp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/imgrecyclerviewscan"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/img_contentlogoscan"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:maxLength="20"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_contentdetailscan"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_light"
        android:text="@string/email"
        android:textColor="@color/textcolor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/img_contentlogoscan"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/img_contentlogoscan"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/img_contentlogoscan"
        android:maxLength="20"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_contentlogoscan"
        android:layout_width="22dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_clipboard_ic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/txt_contentdetailscan"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgrecyclerviewscan"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txt_detailscan"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_10sdp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_5sdp"

        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_20sdp"
        android:id="@+id/btn_deleteqrscan"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_option_dots"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

From Here I am getting the Image and setting this to ImageBitmap

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemHolder, position: Int) {

    val toDoEntityDataScanned: TodoEntityScanned = arrayList.get(position)
    val path = ":/storage/emulated/0/Maximus/QRScanned/"
    val filename = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf("/") + 1)

    val image = File(toDoEntityDataScanned.imagesPathDatascanned, filename)
    val bmOptions = BitmapFactory.Options()
    var bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image.absolutePath, bmOptions)

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener{
        cellClickListenerScanned.onCellClickListenerScanned(arrayList[position])
    }

    holder.itemView.btn_deleteqrscan.setOnClickListener{
        cellClickListenerScanned.oncellDeleteListenerScanned(arrayList[position])
        arrayList.removeAt(position)
        notifyItemRemoved(position)
    }

    holder.images.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    holder.logodetail.text = toDoEntityDataScanned.texttypedatascanned
    holder.contentdetail.text = toDoEntityDataScanned.qrcreatedtextdatascanned
    if (Utils.isURLCheck(holder.contentdetail.text as String)){
        Toast.makeText(context,"U"+holder.contentdetail,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}
```

I am confused why sometime the Image not show in the Layout...

Answer (score 0):

Just compress the bitmap like this

bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 75 /*quality setting*/, outputStream);